# Cannot find module for routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I'm getting the error: Cannot find module '.app/routes/favourite.routes' and I'm not sure why this error is occuring. I've double checked the naming and the path and it appears to be the exact same.

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dbConfig = require("./app/config/db.config");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./app/models");
const Role = db.role;

db.mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb+srv://tami00:MEUxClWqUNbLz359@cluster0.gmvao.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    initial();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// simple route
app.use('/favourite', require('.app/routes/favourite.routes'));

// routes
// require(".app/routes/favourite.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/user.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

function initial() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "creator"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'creator' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "watcher"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'watcher' to roles collection");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

and here is my favourite.routes.js file. I have no issue with the other 2 routes.

```
const express =  require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const{Favourite} = require("../models/favourite.model");
const {auth} = require("../middlewares/authJwt");

router.post("/favouriteNumber", auth, (req, res) => {
    Favourite.find({"movieId": req.body.movieId})
        .exec((err, favourite) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).send(err)
            res.status(200).json({success: true, favouriteNumber: favourite.length})
        })
})

router.post("/favourited", auth, (req, res) => {
    Favourite.find({"movieId": req.body.movieId, "userFrom": req.body.userFrom})
        .exec((err, favourite) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).send(err) 

            let result = false;
            if(favourite.length !== 0) {
                result = true
            }

            res.status(200).json({success: true, favourited: result});


        })
})

router.post("/addToFavourite", auth, (req, res) => {
    
    const favourite = new Favourite(req.body)

    favourite.save((err, doc) => {
        if(err) return res.json({success: false, err})
        return res.status(200).json({success: true, doc})
    })
})

router.post("/removeFavorite", auth, (req, res) => {
    
    Favourite.findOneAndDelete({movieId: req.body.movieId, userFrom: req.body.userFrom})
        .exec((err, doc) => {
            if(err) return res.json({success: false, err})
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, doc})
        })
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is the folder structure of my project

```
Project
 |   
 +-- backend
   |  
    +-- app
       |  
       +-- config (folder)
       +-- controllers (folder)
       +-- middlewares (folder)
       +-- models (folder)
       +-- routes (folder)
       |   |  
       |   +-- favourite.routes.js
       |   +-- auth.routes.js
       |   +-- user.routes.js
       +-- server.js (file)
```

In the command line I

```
C:\Users\tamia\Downloads\proj\backend> npm start
```

Comment: Please post a listing of the files in question (folder structure), also how are you running your app? the command line please, with the directory you are in when you run it.

Comment: @t3dodson I've edited it there thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u missed / before app
Try using `./app/routes/favourite.routes`

Comment: I'm now getting the error Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] do you know why this may be?